# Bash script iteratively per subject

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a bash script that performs a function (neuroscience software) on all subjects in a given path `/home/freesurfer/subjects` but I don't know how to iteratively create output directories for each subject.

I can do this for an individual subject just fine because I explicitly state the specified input and output path, but I'm not sure how to do this for multiple subjects.

The function works like this:

```
command -i < path to data> -s < path to output>
```

How can I achieve same for multiple subjects?

Comment: How are the input and output paths related? Output path name can be generated from input path?

Comment: Mmmm... you have a script that we can't see, that processes some directories we can't see either, that takes some parameters we don't know and does...?

Comment: `for i in /home/freesurfer/subjects/*; do subject="${i##*/}"; command -i "/path/to/data/$subject" -s "/path/to/${subject}.out"; ...; done`? You can use *parameter expansions* to isolate the subject and then use that however you need to adjust your data and output paths.